# Limited home screen

Tags: applications, tablet, home-screen, kiosk-mode

I need to get a company tablet for operators to use at home to check some data while away from company. Since I don't trust them much, I would like to allow only a few apps to be ran on the android tablet and disable anything else inlcuding play store, settings, web browsing, etc...is there any FREE app that can do what I want?

I would also like avoiding somebody logging in with their own account onto the tablet. Thank you.

Comment: I'll look into it, but `"Since I don't trust them much"` stood out to me. If they are not trustworthy maybe don't give them tablets, or adopt a BYOD (bring your own device) methodology?

Comment: I've just added the [kiosk-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/kiosk-mode/info) tag to your question. Check [questions using it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) for existing solutions, as that seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's currently no way to do what you want with an app. You'd need to develop a custom ROM to suit your requirements (or pay someone to do it, of course).

The new Lollipop version of Android has some features to enable [kiosk-mode](/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode)-type applications, so it may be that some apps might come along in future to enable this kind of use.

Slightly off the topic of Android, to amplify what RossC has already said: if you don't trust someone, you probably shouldn't have hired them, and you certainly shouldn't send work to their home. If the worst thing they can do to your business is install an app on your tablet, their job can't be responsible enough to warrant giving them remote access to confidential business data in the first place.

Comment: I presume he means he doesn't trust them *technically* as opposed to *personally*, i.e. he's not concerned that they'll use the device to do nefarious things behind his back, he's concerned that if they have free rein to tinker with it, they might mess it up, and he wants to limit its use to work-related purposes. (Though personally I'd resent it if any employer expected me to carry a mobile device around when I'm not at work but not let me use it for personal purposes as well, forcing me to have two devices on me at all times. It would probably be enough to make me look for a different job.)

Comment: ...I suppose it's a different story if he only wants them to check data at particular times, and they can leave the company device on a shelf except when they're checking the data.

Comment: They need to carry the device home to check status of the production machines few times during the weekend. Would be nice not to find my tablet messed up, or misconfigured each time it comes back, so kiosk would be perfect.